# Selection on tab Items not working WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I want load some data in  two listviews , each of listview is in a separate TabItem.
My problem is that I can load data in listviews but I can not select items from listliews.

My code is looking something like this:

```
  private void populateLoadedTab(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
         if (tab1.IsSelected)
            {

                SesizariList.ItemsSource = sesizari; 
                SesizariList.Items.Refresh();

            }
            else if (tab2.IsSelected)
            {
                    InterventiiList.ItemsSource = interventii;
                    InterventiiList.Items.Refresh();
            }


        }
```

My XAML code is like this :

```html
<TabControl Name="TabCtrlSI" SelectionChanged="populateLoadedTab">
  <TabItem x:Name="tab1"></TabItem> 
  <TabItem x:Name="tab2"></TabItem> 
</TabControl>
```

```html
<ListView Name="SesizariList"/>
<ListView Name="InterventiiList"/>
```

Why I can not select items from listview?
Can I use something else instead of IsSelected?

Comment: Not enough information, you'll need to post a [minimum working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Comment: This is my working example, excepting that in each if I have a query like this: `var sesizari = getsesizari();` respectively  `var interventii = getInterventii();` which return data from database using Entity Framework.

Comment: Could you post some code showing your implementing the ListViews?  I only see the Tab Items.